# Preserving the dimensions of a slice from a Numpy 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a 3d array, `a`, of shape say `a.shape = (10, 10, 10)`

When slicing, the dimensions are `squeezed` automatically i.e.

`a[:,:,5].shape = (10, 10)`

I'd like to preserve the number of dimensions *but also ensure that the dimension that was squeezed is the one that shows 1* i.e.

`a[:,:,5].shape = (10, 10, 1)`

I have thought of re-casting the array and passing `ndmin` but that just adds the extra dimensions to the start of the shape tuple regardless of where the slice came from in the array `a`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
a[:,:,[5]].shape
# (10,10,1)
```

---

`a[:,:,5]` is an example of [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

`a[:,:,[5]]` is an example of [integer array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -- [combined with basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing). When using integer array indexing the resultant shape is always ["identical to the (broadcast) indexing array shapes"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). Since `[5]` (as an array) has shape `(1,)`, 
`a[:,:,[5]]` ends up having shape `(10,10,1)`.

Comment: Thanks, however I should add that I am implementing a `__getitem__` method and so I'm reluctant to alter the slice arguments - see the edit

Comment: numpy's rules for indexing are complicated enough. Creating a `__getitem__` that alters those rules may be asking for trouble. Wouldn't it be better to demand users of your object understand numpy's rules and pass the correct index?

Comment: Very nice, would you mind pointing us to the part of the numpy documentation that explains this behavior?

Comment: @BastianVenthur: I've added an explanation with links to the docs.